# How to fix END$$ error with a DO function in PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql, syntax

I don't understand why I get an error on the line with the : "END $$"

```
DO $$
BEGIN
DECLARE 
    i INT := 0;
    j INT := i + 1;
    numberUsers INT;
    BEGIN
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO numberUsers FROM "WU_Users";
        WHILE i <= numberUsers LOOP
        i := i + 1; 
    END LOOP;
END $$;
```

The error :

```
ERREUR:  erreur de syntaxe à la fin de l'entrée
LIGNE 12 : END $$;
```

Kind Regards !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indent properly, then it will become clear. The block structure is

```
DECLARE  /* optional */
BEGIN
EXCEPTION  /* optional */
END;
```

To format your code:

```
DO $$
BEGIN
    DECLARE 
        i INT := 0;
        j INT := i + 1;
        numberUsers INT;
    BEGIN
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO numberUsers FROM "WU_Users";
        WHILE i <= numberUsers LOOP
            i := i + 1; 
        END LOOP;
    /* --> missing END; here <--- */
END $$;
```

Alternatively, you could remove the `BEGIN` at the beginning, since that outermost block just contains another block.

Comment: Why there is a end missing ? I don't understand ? Like, The "END LOOP" is the end of the while but we can't write a "BEGIN" under the while  ?

Comment: Look at the indentation. The missing `END;` belongs to the block indented 4 spaces.